# Dealing with CheckBoxList in Asp.net Mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to implement a Simple Employee Registration where employee enter his name and select his  skill set using a check box list,I have to post these data when the user click the submit button
The problem is that I want to use `@html.Checkbox` rather than `input type="checkbox"`
and I need to retrieve the details of employee name and skill set in the `post` method,

I made the view as I expected using input type="check box", but I am not satisfied with it.

Here is my code that I have tried.

**Class**

```
   public class Employee
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Select your Skills")]

    public IList<string> Proficiency { get; set; }

}
public class SkillSet
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Skill { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }


}
 public ActionResult Register()
    {
        IEnumerable<SkillSet> langset = new List<SkillSet> { 

        new SkillSet{ID=1,Selected=true,Skill="ASP.NET"},
        new SkillSet{ID=2,Selected=false,Skill="JAVA"},
        new SkillSet{ID=3,Selected=false,Skill="PHP"},
        new SkillSet{ID=4,Selected=false,Skill="JQUERY"},
        new SkillSet{ID=5,Selected=false,Skill="SQL"}
        };
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        ViewBag.Language = langset;
        return View(emp);
    }
```

***HTML***

```
@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Name)




    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.Proficiency)

    @foreach (var item in EmpSkill)
    {
     <input type="checkbox" value="@item.Skill" name="@Model.Proficiency" checked="@item.Selected" />@item.Skill
    }
    <input type ="submit" value="Finish" />
```

Please provide a solution.